# Динамическое добавление QLineEdit. Возникло исключение: Exception at 0x7fffb3d838fa, code: 0xc0000005

Tags: c++, qt, исключения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно добавлять QLabel, QLineEdit относительно того сколько полей в БД?
У меня выбрасывает на этой строчке программа :`labelsAnalysisColumn[n]->setText(recordTable.fieldName(n));`

Сам кусок кода такой :

```
bool queryTableAnalysisRes = queryAnalysis->exec("SELECT * FROM public.analysis");
QSqlRecord recordTable = queryAnalysis->record();
int count = recordTable.count();
if (queryTableAnalysisRes) {
    QLabel **labelsAnalysisColumn = new QLabel*[count];
    QLineEdit **LineEditAnalysisColumn = new QLineEdit*[count];
    for (int n=0; n<count; n++) {
        labelsAnalysisColumn[n]->setText(recordTable.fieldName(n));
        AnalysisLayout->addWidget(labelsAnalysisColumn[n], n, 0);
        QSqlField fieldTable = recordTable.field(n);
        if (fieldTable.type() == QVariant::String) {
           AnalysisListLineEdit.append(LineEditAnalysisColumn[n]);
           AnalysisLayout->addWidget(LineEditAnalysisColumn[n], n, 1);
        } else if (fieldTable.type() == QVariant::LongLong) {
           AnalysisLayout->addWidget(ComboBoxAnalysis, n, 1);
           AnalysisComboBox.append(ComboBoxAnalysis);
        }
        AnalysisColumnName.append(recordTable.fieldName(n));
    }
} else {
    dbError = connFormAnalysis.mydb.lastError();
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Ошибка", dbError.text(), QMessageBox::Close);
}

QDynamicButton *buttonAdd = new QDynamicButton(this,AnalysisColumnName,AnalysisListLineEdit,AnalysisComboBox,AnalysisListTableView); // Создаем объект динамической кнопки
buttonAdd->setText(tr("ДОБАВИТЬ ЗАПИСЬ"));
AnalysisLayout->addWidget(buttonAdd,count,0,1,3);
connect(buttonAdd, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=] () { AddNote(); });

AnalysisLayout->addWidget(TableAnalysis, 0, 3, count+1, 1);
WidgetAnalysis->setLayout(AnalysisLayout);
connFormAnalysis.connClose();
```

Comment: Кажется я понял как решить данную проблему с помощью QVector. https://secretsilent.ru/qt-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/

Comment: вы неправильно выделяете память под лейблы `QLabel **labelsAnalysisColumn = new QLabel*[count];` тут вы создаете массив указателей, но сами элементы в нем еще не созданы